# Editing already existing method

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm using the Slick library as the framework for my small game. Linebreaks ain't supported by default on the Graphics2d object. However, i found this little fix:

```
private void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
    for (String line : text.split("\n"))
        g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
}
```

As i am very new to Java, i am not sure what the easiest way to implement this would be, and would really love some help! :-)

Comment: what is the problem with above approach? can you be clearer what sort of help?

Comment: Well, where can i put this code? 
If i commandclick the drawString method, it takes me to the class, but it says the method itself is compiled and read-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want in your case is :

**a)** To overload the given method (in case you have access to the class and maybe add one more parameter )

example :

`private void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y,boolean test)`

and pass a true on test or something like that but this is a crude way of doing things

**b)** Otherwise you could just extend the class that implements your method and re implement the method as you wish in the extended class

**c)** or as a third alternative which maybe is the most viable in this case is to just edit the original method as @user1594895 states, but in this case you must be sure you won't make any use of the original method otherwise consider doing **a)** or **b)**

Let me know what kind of approach you've decided to use.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is: download the sources of the Silk library you're using, you can download https://bitbucket.org/kevglass/slick.

Editing method you specified. Build it and include it in your project.
With IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse is simple.

You should submit a bug with relative patch so that it is integrated in the general library.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way (which is already mentioned in your own post) which you should apply when you only call this method from one class:
Just insert the code snippet above in your  class, then you call it like any other method..it's kind of an helper method then. (just ask If you don't get what I mean)

---

Another easy way to do is - if the class is not final - is just to extend the class and override the method:

```
public class MyGraphics extends Graphics {
      @Override
      public void drawString(String text, int x, int y) {
         for (String line : text.split("\n"))
            super.drawString(line, x, y += getFontMetrics().getHeight());
      }
}
```

Then you just work with your own class - which is exactly the same as the other class, expect your `drawString` Method is different, you would instantiate it like this: `Graphics g = new MyGrpahics();`